# automapper precondition not working when the condition is not equal to null

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using the Automapper, and I have fields which sometimes could be null. I want to do some stuff on the value before the Map if the value is not null, so I did this

```
  .ForMember(dest => dest.PersianEndDate, opt =>
   {
      opt.PreCondition(src => src.EndDate != null);                    
      opt.MapFrom(src => src.EndDate.Value.toShamsi().ToString());
   })
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Why? What happens without the precondition that you don't want? A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do similar to cover the Null value case as well, so your code should be like this:

```
  .ForMember(dest => dest.PersianEndDate, opt =>
   {
      opt.PreCondition(src => src.EndDate != null);                    
      opt.MapFrom(src => src.EndDate.Value.toShamsi().ToString());
   })
  .ForMember(dest => dest.PersianEndDate, opt =>
   {
      opt.PreCondition(src => src.EndDate == null);                    
      opt.MapFrom(src => DateTime.Now.toShamsi().ToString()); // change this line as you wish, for null case.
   })
```